# How do I return a single random row from a model?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Trying to get a single random row from a model. I pulled this from the web:

```
$this->Testimonial->findAll(null,null,'rand()',1,null,null);
```

Unfortunately findAll doesn't exist anymore in cakephp 1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$this->Quote->find('first', array('order' => array('rand()')))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
$count = $this->Testimonial->find('count');
$this->Testimonial->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => rand(1,$count))));
```

(this also doesn't retrieve "all" the results)

Comment: What if my IDs are not in sequential order?

Comment: then you just retrieve all the results and then pick a random one,

`$find = $this->Model->find('all');
echo $find[rand(0,count($find))]['Model']['someName']`

Comment: @Thomas: that wastes a lot of ressources, since all the data has to be put from the database to PHP just to get thrown away. Better let the DB server deal with the picking of the right data set.